How can I test my pc speed performance?
I want to see whether my Windows PC performance degrades over time.  So, essentially "how fast does this run software like MS Word, etc.?"
What's an easy way to test it's performance?

so I usually test the cooling system, by running prime95, and watching the temp. I consider a system stable if I can run it for 3 days without ever exceeding the thresholds I desire (80-90C), and when I stop prime, CPU temp should take less than 10 seconds to drop each increment of 10C, and returns to within 10C of room temp inside a minute.

The PC is a very complex system. Software can (and will!) slow down without hardware slowdown. I think it is pointless to get at this with synthetic benchmarks. Only you can decide when slower becomes too slow.

@DanielB, I agree. I'm seeing other people at work with 4 or 5 year old laptops complaining about their speed. I suspect it's a software issue. I want a benchmark for myself to confirm (in 5 years :)  that it's a software issue.

Did you look through the internet for ways to test PC performance? Are you asking the question you're actually facing, or the question you THINK is the right one? From your comment it sounds as though you're facing an existing PC performance issue, which means you don't really need to test your performance because it's already known to be affected by SOMETHING. Asking us for performance test tool recommendations is off topic, asking about your actual problem may not be. I recommend you reconsider your question and EDIT it as appropriate so we can help you solve the real problem.

If you're looking for benchmark software, there is more than one that
you may choose:

PassMark is the best-known, but many
of its tests are paid versions with trial.
UserBenchMark
Geekbench
Novabench

